# plotly tooltip names returned from ggplot function

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly

I have defined a function that takes a data.frame and returns a plot, which I later on pass to `plotly`. I need this function to be flexible and it's going to be called a number of times (that's why I wrote a function). A simple reproducible example:

```
a <- data.frame(x = 1:3, y = c(2, 6, 3))
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)

plotTrend <- function(x){
   var1 <- names(x)[1]
   var2 <- names(x)[2]
   p <- ggplot(a, aes(x = get(var1), y = get(var2)))+
           geom_point()+
           geom_smooth(method = "lm")
   return(p)
}
```

Of course I can call `plotTrend` on `a` and I'll get the plot I'm expecting.

But when I call `ggplotly` on it, the tooltip reads an ugly `get(var1)` instead of the name of the column ("x" in this example).

```
plotTrend(a)
ggplotly()
```

I'm aware I could create a text column for the data.frame inside the function, and call `ggplotly(tooltip = "text")` (I read plenty of questions in SO about that), but I wondered if there's another way to get the right names in the tooltips, either by modifying the function or by using some special argument in `ggplotly`.

My expected output is:

- A plotly plot with
- Tooltips that accurately read the values and whose names are "x" and "y"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `aes_string` to display the evaluated column names in the `ggplotly` tooltips:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)

a <- data.frame(x = 1:3, y = c(2, 6, 3))

var1 <- names(a)[1]
var2 <- names(a)[2]

p <- ggplot(a, aes_string(x = var1, y = var2)) +
    geom_point()+
    geom_smooth(method = "lm") 

ggplotly(p)
```

[image]

NB: this works the same inside the `plotTrend` function call.

---

Alternatively, use tidy evaluation to pass the column names as function arguments in the `plotTrend` function:

```r
plotTrend <- function(data, x, y) {

  x_var <- enquo(x)
  y_var <- enquo(y)

  p <- ggplot(data, aes(x = !!x_var, y = !!y_var)) +
      geom_point()+
      geom_smooth(method = "lm") 

  return(p)

}

plotTrend(a, x = x, y = y) %>%
    ggplotly()
```